# How to change source of Button in ListView?

Tags: android

I know, similar questions (ListView selected items are messed up when scroll the ListView...) are asked before and the answer is doing operation in `onItemClick`, not in `getView`.

My situation is a little bit complicated. I have a custom view in each ListView row. This custom view has 5 ImageViews. So I catch onClick event of these ImageViews and change drawable image. In this case, I don't know how to move this operation to onItemClick. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

do like this. you can change the color or background of selected item on listview. use this code in getView() method.

```
m_Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                indexClick = position;
                indexClickFlag = true;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.i("in click--------->", "" + position);
                Intent i = new Intent(ArtistPlaylistActivity.this,
                        PlayerMainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("songnameIndexinPlaylist", position);
                startActivity(i);
                ArtistPlaylistActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
        if (indexClickFlag) {
            if ((indexClick) == (position)) {
                itemLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_select);
                Log.d("System out", "iclick" + indexClick + "pos"
                        + position);

            }
        }
```

where, int indexClick ; boolean indexClickFlag = false;
itemLayout -- > is layout that background that you want to change and m_Button.

Hope helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Child from the view using `getChildAt(index)` method. put the index of image view to get the image view object

**Sample Code**

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(".....view..."+arg1);
    LinearLayout ll =(LinearLayout) arg1;
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) ll.getChildAt(0);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
```

Comment: No, I have multiple buttons on rows of ListView. I just want to change background image of `clicked` button, not clicked item...